# integrate / build 'weather radar' widget

Tags: jquery, python, django, weather

I'm looking to integrate a 'weather radar' widget into a site I'm building.

The only available resource I can find is: http://www.meteoonline.co.uk/gadgets/Europe/Netherlands/135

- which basically delivers a flash mov in a iframe ! urrrgh! - and 'permission denied' of course with any javascript interaction on the iframe..

Can anyone suggest an alternative resource / or approach ?

I'm happy to work with the raw data if I can get it .. any ideas welcome !

> site is like >[ html5 + jquery on django ]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

-> Find an RSS feed of radar images for your target area

this one works for me : http://rss.buienradar.nl/radar.php

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion would be to check [Programmable Web](http://www.programmableweb.com/) to see what APIs are available for weather data. A quick scan shows they had a [blog post about 5 weather APIs](http://blog.programmableweb.com/2009/04/15/5-weather-apis-from-weatherbug-to-weather-channel/) last year
and [filtering by 'weather' category](http://www.programmableweb.com/apis/directory/1?apicat=Weather) I see 10 available now. I don't know if any of them have a radar but it would be a good place to start.

Comment: thanks thats a great resource. I didnt find anything there.. but gave me the motivation to search harder :)